# Is $\lfloor \log_{2}(n-1) \rfloor + 1 = \lceil \log_{2}(n) \rceil$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , $n \geq 2$?

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to solve a problem where I get in the solution that the answer is $\lfloor \log_{2}(n-1) \rfloor + 1$, but the solution book has as an answer the value $\lceil \log_{2}(n) \rceil$. I was wondering are these two exactly the same?

I plotted their difference on [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20floor(log_%7B2%7D(n-1))%20%2B%201%20-%20ceil(log_%7B2%7D(n))%20for%20n%3D2%20to%2010003333) and it seems to be $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that the following claim is true.

> If $x<y$ and there is no integer in the open interval $(x,y)$, then $\lfloor x \rfloor + 1 = \lceil y \rceil.$

Now convince yourself that there is no integer strictly between $\log_2(n-1)$ and $\log_2(n)$.